# What could corrupt all files I upload using base64?

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, base64

I'm currently trying to upload specific file formats in `laravel` and `vue` using `base64`. Even though the files are successfully uploaded and shows the format of the file types in the file's folder, they all are corrupt and cannot open. Not sure what I'm not doing rightly. Below is my code.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        //$this->validateRequest();



        if($request->file){
            $file = $request->file;
            $pos  = strpos($file, ';');
            $file_type = explode(':', substr($file, 0, $pos))[1]; //returns the file type
            $allowed_file_types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg','image/jpg','application/pdf'];

            //dd(getfilesize($request->file));

           if(in_array($file_type, $allowed_file_types))
            {
                $base = base64_decode($file);
                $file_size = strlen(base64_decode($file));

                if($file_size > 2097152 ){ //2mb
                    return [ 'message' => 'File size too large'];
                }
                $ready_file = time().'.' . explode('/', explode(':', substr($file, 0, strpos($file, ';')))[1])[1];
                $destinationPath = public_path() . "/uploads/user_files/" . $ready_file;             
                file_put_contents($destinationPath, $base);

            }


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to decode the wrong thing.

```
$base = base64_decode($file);
```

`$file` still contains the full Data URI, `data:image/png;base64,ABCD…` - what you want to decode, is the `ABCD…` part only.